# Открывается консоль в WinForms проекте

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Я сделал WinForms проект в Goormide, загрузил, чтобы протестировать и увидел что вместе с самой формой открывается консоль.

[image: Экран]

В коде формы нет упоминания о консоли. Эта проблема не зависит от онлайн компилятора. Скачивая программу с GitPod, консоль остается.

Comment: net core или net framework?

Comment: думаю при сборке проекта указывалось  console application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[goormIDE](https://ide.goorm.io/) использует компилятор Mono. Для того чтобы он собрал оконное приложение без консоли нужно задать флаг `-target:winexe` (см. [FAQ: Winforms](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/winforms/)).

Для этого нужно открыть в goormIDE скрипт сборки. По умолчанию там стоит что-то вроде.

```
mkdir -p ${cs.set.build.path} && mcs $(find ${cs.set.src.path} -name *.cs) -out:${cs.set.build.path}/${cs.set.main.name}.exe ${cs.set.build.options}
```

Нужно добавить флаг:

```
mkdir -p ${cs.set.build.path} && mcs $(find ${cs.set.src.path} -name *.cs) -target:winexe -out:${cs.set.build.path}/${cs.set.main.name}.exe ${cs.set.build.options}
```

После этого собранное приложение будет открываться без консоли.

P.S. Можно им в поддержку написать чтобы изменили команду сборки по-умолчанию для Windows Forms. Мне почему-то это делать лень.

Comment: А как быть с командой старта (а не сборки)?

Comment: @GREATDNG Если честно плохо помню goorm :) Что не так с командой старта? Вы же просто exe-шник запускали, нет?

Comment: Там если ее запустить, то консольный exe создаст.

Comment: @GREATDNG Что-то у меня не получилось воспроизвести. Вы действительно запускаете WinForms на сервере? Команда старта по умолчанию, имхо, расчитана на веб-приложения. Если Вы не используете nginx, то попробуйте заменить команду старта на команду сборки. Либо пропишите для mcs такой же флаг (`-target:winexe`)

Comment: Да, я знаю что можно просто заменить команду, но хотелось бы чтобы после выполнения на сервере (иногда мне это нужно чтобы узнать баг в самом начале программы - JIT компилятор почему-то не выдает окно с ошибкой), исполняемый файл функционровал нормально (без консоли).